# I want to run flutter on windows 7 with my android phone as a emulator . truned on my debugging mode. How can i fix issue of flutter doctor command

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

[√] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept licences agreement from the android SDK

You can type this command `sdkmanager --licenses` or navigate to your SDK folder and type `tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`.

This will ask you if you want to review non-accepeted licenses. You just have to type `y` to accept or `n` if you want to decline.

PS: Don't forget to connect your device and test debug mode with `adb devices`

Answer (score 0):

Open VS Code, then download Dart and flutter plugin. Don't forget to implement the fix given by @user8773560